# Слово "щиколотка"

Tags: этимология

А что вообще за слово "щиколотка" (что оно означает, я в курсе)? Какая у него этимология?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интересное слово. Нашла разъяснение в словаре П.Я.Черных. Там приводится простонародная форма *щИколка*. Похожие слова есть только в укр. языке (щИколотка, щИколодка) и белор. яз. (шчыкалатка). В других славянских языка оно отсутствует. В русском языке слово фиксируется с конца 18 в. (в словарях - щиколОток). Как пишет П.Я. Черных, "слово очень темное". Возможно, современная форма *щиколотка* происходит от более древней *щиколка*  - фонетического варианта диалектного слова *чИкалка* (от "чикать" - 'бить палкой') - вологод. 'палка, коею бьют чиж или мяч', 'лапта' (Даль). Так могла называться сначала вся голень. Если это предположение себя оправдало бы, то **щиколотка** можно было бы объяснить как производное от *щикала* или *щикало* с суффиксом -от-ь (щикАлоть), откуда и щикАлотка. Написание О (после корневого К) в этом случае следовало бы считать таким же ошибочным, как, напр., в *ласкОвый* (вместо *ласкАвый*). (Историко-этимологический словарь П.Я.Черных)